# CASE WHEN LIKE query SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, case, sql-like

Could you tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT Students.Class
FROM Students
GROUP BY Students.class
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '*a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > COUNT(*)/2;
```

I have to check if the name ends with the letter 'a' and then compare if amount of these names in every class is higher than the half of all students in these classes.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it. It says that there's a syntax error(no operator) in the last query's line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does not support `case`.

```
SELECT Students.Class
FROM Students
GROUP BY Students.class
HAVING SUM(IIF(Name LIKE '*a', 1, 0)) > COUNT(*)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to display only classes:

```
Select Class
From Students
Where Name Like '*a'
Group by Class
Having SUM(*) > (Select COUNT(*)/2 
                From Students)
```

Comment: Ms-access says there's a syntax error in this query.

Comment: It is logically correct query, the syntax error is something small I cannot catch by just looking at it. I have to check it in compiler. What is the error you get ?

Comment: It only informs about a syntax error in query 'SUM(*) > SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM Students'.

Comment: Try Select Class
From Students
Where Name Like '*a'
Group by Class
Having SUM(*) > **(Select COUNT(*)/2 
                From Students)**

Comment: Now it adds there is no operator in SUM(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM STUDENTS).

Comment: oops I have forgoten that it is not SUM() but SUM(*)  , notice the asterisk. Just copy the edited Answer I have given above.

Comment: Yes, I've already realised there sould be an asterisk but it keeps telling me this error. :/